# Xubuntu window bar font not rendering properly with dark themes

Tags: xubuntu, themes, fonts, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 and when I change to a dark theme, like *Greybird-dark* or *Adwaita-dark* which are preinstalled by default, the window bar is not rendered properly and looks really ugly (see the screenshot below):

[image: window bar not rendered properly]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ugly" is a relative term. The theme developpers may like that. Indeed, you may want to change your window theme. In XFCE, use Window Manager settings to set a different window theme (i.e., the look of (legacy) window decorations: title and border). That theme for the window decorations is independent from the theme used by the application (for rendering widgets, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Xfce uses two different themes for the window borders (window manager theme) and the window content (GTK theme). The first can be set using the Window Manager application, while the latter is set using the Appearance application.

The problem you are facing occurs in Xfce when you are using the default *Greybird* window manager theme with a dark GTK theme. The solution is pretty simple if you wish to use *Greybird* as your window manager theme:

1. Open Window Manager.
2. In the *Style* tab search for and select the *Greybird-dark* theme.
3. Click *Close* to close the window.
4. You may need to restart the open applications for the theme to apply.

Dark themes should now work correctly, with white-colored fonts in the window title bar.

Answer (score 0):

It must be some bug because it's actually unreadable for me at least. You could change the window manager font and see which one works best.